# Selenium chrome driver пропадает плагин после перезагрузки

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-extension

Использую селениум и хромдрайвер для простого скрапинга. Открываю страницу и ставлю "паузу".

```
self.driver.get(self.start_urls[0])
input("Press after log in")
```

Далее вручную скачиваю плагин и делаю все дела. Проблема в том, что в следующий раз, когда запускаю драйвер скаченного хром плагина нет, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно скачать расширение (.crx файл), затем добавить его опцией

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver


options = Options()
options.add_extension('/path/to/extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Скачать расширение можно, например, на этом сайте http://crxextractor.com/